# C++ Question about Char Strings and Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm fairly new to C++ and still trying to understand Pointers and when they are needed or not. But for this question, I was looking around to creating header files and classes.
My first "test" was to just create a class that can handle "Logs" So I did this.

Logger.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger();
        void logC(const char* message);
        void logCA(const char message[]);
        void logS(string message);
};
```

Logger.cpp

```
#include "Logger.h"

Logger::Logger() {

}

void Logger::logC(const char* message)
{
    cout << message << endl;
}

void Logger::logCA(const char message[])
{
    cout << message << endl;
}

void Logger::logS(string message)
{
    cout << message << endl;
}
```

And then on my main function I just use them like this.

```
#include "Logger.h"

int main(){

    Logger myLogger;

    myLogger.logC("Hello");
    myLogger.logCA("Alo");
    myLogger.logS("Hola");

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Few questions here. Why would I use one method over the others. And also, on the const char* method, why is this is a pointer to a char it takes a char array as valid and also, if it's receiving an address to the location of a char, why the output is the whole array and not the memory address it's on. (And it also "knows" where to stop, it doesn't print from that address and forever)

Comment: When declared as an argument, array declarations are translated as *pointers*. This means that `const char message[]` is really equal to `const char* message`.

Comment: please keep one question per post. and *Why would I use one method over the others* just not a good question if you do not have specific use case.

Comment: If you are really new to c++, I'd suggest simply don't use pointer, you can back to it after you understand some c++ concept.

Comment: Well, in this case there is an specific use case. Logging strings to console is the use case.

Comment: That's the overarching goal. apple apple is talking at a lower level: a use case for a specific way to go about reaching that goal. "Logging strings to console" can be done in many, many different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void logC(const char* message);
```

Accepts a pointer to a `char` buffer. This is also known as a C-string (as long as it's null terminated, which yours is, because it's a string literal).

```
void logCA(const char message[]);
```

*Exactly the same*. Don't let the `[]` fool you: this is literally the same as `const char* message`. That's not because arrays are pointers: they're not. It's a weird oddity from C history. A function parameter with what *looks* like "array type" with no dimensions, is treated as a pointer parameter instead. Yuck!

```
void logS(string message);
```

Accepts a `std::string`. These can be constructed from C-strings, and this is happening for you behind the scenes when you pass in your string literal.

Which is best? That's highly subjective. Arguably you want a `const std::string_view`, which can accept any of these at no cost. But a deep discussion on the differences is out of scope here; it can be found in your book, however.

> it's receiving an address to the location of a char, why the output is the whole array and not the memory address it's on

Because `cout` has a special rule for `char*`, knowing that you *usually* want these to be treated like strings, because you do. Instead of printing the pointer's value (a memory address), it dereferences that and prints all the characters in the buffer it points to, ending at the null terminator. It's a feature.

If you use a cast to another pointer type, you can "turn that off", e.g. `cout << (void*)message` now you'll see an address.